# Save menu current position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website where I have a drop down menu, i.e. the main category, sub-category and sub-category of the 2nd level. After selecting the sub-category 1 or 2 level, the identifier of the clicked sub-category is saved to localStorage.

My problem is that after switching to another subpage, the entire menu is curled up, and now I would like the menu to expand to the level of the subcategory that I clicked after entering the new subpage. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it :(

My code: jsfiddle.net/reverse26/4z93kv1n/2/

When you select a sub-category, localStorage is updated and the last-clicked sub-category is saved in it. You can check it yourself by going to the website. My menu is created dynamically in Symfony

Comment: Linking to your own site is not recommended, since this question/answer will then be useless to anyone searching in future. If you can't recreate this using code snippets here, I'd recommend recreating at codepen or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Ok, i edit now my code :)

Comment: What is problem if you have saved in localstorage last-clicked position? Just expand that menu when next page is loaded :)

Comment: Well the problem is the development of this menu :( Frontend is unfortunately black magic for me. In localStorage, I have an ID subcategory and I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Well, here is some idea...try to figure out how to make it work :D i am too lazy to create in my pc, and on jsfiddle i can't test it 
http://jsfiddle.net/4z93kv1n/7/

Comment: Not working ;/ After switching to the subpage the menu is collapsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to save the last category/subcategory identifier to localStorage and each time the page was loaded, to check which category/subcategory was last clicked, on this basis js changed the display:none of this block to display:block